# Error: "category" is not a registered scale

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to migrate Chart.js from `2.9.3` to `3.3.0` and even after applying the the changes (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html) I'm still getting the error:

`Error: "category" is not a registered scale`.

This is what I have

```
Chart.register(BarController, DoughnutController, LineController, PieController);
```

```
new Chart(this.id, {
    type: 'bar',
    data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
        title: {
            display: options.plugins.title ? true : false,
        },        
        tooltip: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false
        },        
        scales: {
        x: {
            stacked: true,
            gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            display: false,
            },
            ticks: {
            autoSkip: true,
            maxTicksLimit: 13,
            },
        },
        y: {
            stacked: true,
            gridLines: {
            color: '#e6e6e6',
            drawBorder: false,
            },
        }
    }
});
```

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Like the error says you are using the `category scale` so you will need to import and register it like so:

```js
import {CategoryScale} from 'chart.js'; 
Chart.register(CategoryScale);
```

Or you can choose to not use treeshaking and import everything like so:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

For all available things you might need to import and register please take a look here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.0/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc

Comment: where in his code is he actually using the categoryScale? What is the categoryscale?

Comment: That is the default x axis type. Category scale is the scale type with labels you provide, so since he does not change the type of his x axis he is using the category scale, and because the error says so

Comment: @ProblemsOfSumit makes a good point lol. No intuition as to why this error would appear without a deep understanding of the package. Someone should look at fixing/making this clearer.

Comment: Thanks fo ryoue help @LeeLenalee - this helped me overcome this error. However, your answer does appear to assume the reader already has the knowledge you need to fix the error - in which case you would not be asking this question! In particular "Like the error says you are using the `category scale`" - no it doesnt. If the error said "You are using the CategoryScale, but it is not registered" I would say the error said that. I do appreciate you taking the time to answer the question, and I hope you take my feedback in the manner I meant it - as a positive.

Answer (score 77):

If you are using `react-chartjs-2`.

Without tree shaking:

```js
import { Chart as ChartJS } from 'chart.js/auto'
import { Chart }            from 'react-chartjs-2'
```

With tree shaking:

```js
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js'
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2'

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
)
```

Comment: Examples (with imports) added by chart.js in this link https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/line-chart

Answer (score 29):

To use with react-chartjs-2 and import everything; changing chart as chartjs so that it does not show error for importing chart from react chart

```
import { Chart as ChartJS, registerables } from 'chart.js';
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2'
ChartJS.register(...registerables);
```

Answer (score 8):

With NextJS I have to use the following, as internally there is a useEffect in the react-chartjs-2 so all needs to be client rendered:

```
"use client";

import "chart.js/auto";

import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using Line chart , i faced this issue when update to next.js version , below solution works fine for me, resolved that before destroy() chart error

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using "react-chartjs-2" you need to import this too:

```
import "chart.js/auto";
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with my Nextjs/React project
make sure to install WITH the --save flag

```
npm install --save chart.js react-chartjs-2
```

I did everything right but this was the problem.

use this exact npm command and then use this code (Bar chart for example), and all should be good:

```js
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Chart as ChartJS } from "chart.js/auto";

const BarChart = ({ data }) => {
  return <Bar data={data} />;
};

export default BarChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply update the chart.js to latest in your package.json and packagelock.json as well
and do npm istall --force
these error keep coming , you solve one another will come complaining the same .