# Using chartjs and react-chartjs-2 in Remix gets error "react-chartjs-2" was not found in your node_modules

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I installed `chartjs` and `react-chartjs-2` using `yarn add react-chartjs-2 chart.js`. However, when I import any components from the `react-chartjs-2` library, this error is thrown:

```
The path "react-chartjs-2" is imported in [path]\chart.tsx but "react-chartjs-2" was not found in your node_modules. Did you forget to install it?
```

Anyone has any ideas what is the problem here?

I tried this [method](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/faq/esm-only/) by adding this into `package.json` but still didn't work:

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

I also tried using this `npx rmx-cli get-esm-packages react-chartjs-2` to add the dependencies to my serverDependenciesToBundle, still no work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the lastest version of `chartjs` and `react-chartjs-2`, which are v4.0.1 and v5.0.1 respectively. Try downgrading to `"chart.js": "^3.9.1"` and `"react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1"`. This might happen when migrating chartjs from v3 to v4.

And please keep in mind that you need to use chartjs in ClientOnly, because chartjs is DOM canvas based.

Comment: I tried downgrading to your recommended version but getting this error now `Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID '' can be reused.`

Comment: As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74308415/12463093), if you are using React with Typescript import this `import "chart.js/auto";`

Comment: It worked for my legacy project. Thank you