# Using Chart.js in Wix (Velo) and get Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused

Tags: chart.js, velo

I'm using [this tutorial to draw charts using chart.js in Wix Valo](https://www.wix.com/velo/example/chart.js-custom-element)

For create the chart I'm using

```
async function chart(data_chart){

var chart = new ChartJSAPI($w('#customElement1'));

chart.customization = data_chart.customization

chart.data = data_chart.data 
}
```

And it working well

But when I call again to chart function

I got this error

```
chart.js:5552 Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused.
```

I tried to implement this:

[Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused. chart.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68100325/canvas-is-already-in-use-chart-with-id-0-must-be-destroyed-before-the-canvas)

But there is no function

```
chart.destroy();
```

How to destroy it?

Answer (score 2):

After you have created the chart you don't have to re-create it. You can just update the data of the chart by setting `chart.data = newData` and `chart.customization = newCustomization` and then it should update automatically.

Comment: I tried this:


 if(chart1 == undefined){

var chart1 = new ChartJSAPI($w('#customElement1'));
 }


chart1.customization = data_chart.customization

chart1.data = data_chart.data 

And get the same error

Comment: Now it's really strange, when I select Wix publish, it shows this error (I used a different browser and clear catch ) and when I select preview it works fine. Do you have any clue why (I'm a premium Wix user)?   https://ibb.co/h79Fz1z