# I'm trying to use chart.js in angular to create a simple bar chart but I'm getting an error as 'legend' type doesn't exist for options

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

Here is the clear view of the error: Can someone help me resolve it?

> Type '{ legend: { position: string; }; title: { display: true; text:
> string; }; }' is not assignable to type
> '_DeepPartialObject<CoreChartOptions<"bar"> &
> ElementChartOptions<"bar"> & PluginChartOptions<"bar"> &
> DatasetChartOptions<"bar"> & ScaleChartOptions<...> &
> BarControllerChartOptions>'.   Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'legend' does not exist in type
> '_DeepPartialObject<CoreChartOptions<"bar"> &
> ElementChartOptions<"bar"> & PluginChartOptions<"bar"> &
> DatasetChartOptions<"bar"> & ScaleChartOptions<...> &
> BarControllerChartOptions>'.ts(2322) index.esm.d.ts(3599, 3): The
> expected type comes from property 'options' which is declared here on
> type 'ChartConfiguration<"bar", any, unknown>'

Here I have attached my code in my component.ts.

```js
new Chart('myChart',{
       type: 'bar',
       data :{
         labels: this.team,
         datasets: [
           {
             data: this.totalDefects,
             borderColor : '#000000',
             backgroundColor : '#8e5ea2',
             label : "Total defect count",
           }
         ]
       },
       options: {
         legend: {
         position : 'top',
          },
         title:{
           display: true,
           text : 'Total number of defects raised by each team across iterations'
         }
       }
    });
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using v2 syntax with v3, legend and title options have to be configured in the `options.plugins` namespace instead of in the root of the `options` namespace

Comment: thank you so much, I have resolved the issue. But now there are no compilation errors, but the chart is not rendered on the page as I am getting an error ' "bar" is not a registered controller.' Can you please help me out, I'm sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67727684/8682983