# Uncaught Error: "category" is not a registered scale. (vue-chartjs)

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am implementing chart JS on my vue project. Please note that I have read [Error: "category" is not a registered scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67727603/error-category-is-not-a-registered-scale) yet it isn't working.
Versions:

```
 "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
 "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.1",
 "vue": "^3.2.37",
```

My BarChart.Vue:

```
<template>
  <Bar
    :chart-options="chartOptions"
    :chart-data="chartData"
    :chart-id="chartId"
    :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
    :plugins="plugins"
    :css-classes="cssClasses"
    :styles="styles"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale
);

export default {
  name: "BarChart",
  components: { Bar },
  props: {
    chartId: {
      type: String,
      default: "bar-chart",
    },
    datasetIdKey: {
      type: String,
      default: "label",
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400,
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400,
    },
    cssClasses: {
      default: "",
      type: String,
    },
    styles: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
    plugins: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
        datasets: [{ data: [40, 20, 12] }],
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <BarChart ref="bar" />
</template>
```

I always get the error below on my console yet I have registered **CategoryScale**

> chart.mjs:4009 Uncaught Error: "category" is not a registered scale.
> at Registry._get (chart.mjs:4009:13)
> at Registry.getScale (chart.mjs:3964:17)
> at chart.mjs:5592:37
> at each (helpers.segment.mjs:60:12)
> at Chart.buildOrUpdateScales (chart.mjs:5579:5)
> at Chart._updateScales (chart.mjs:5726:10)
> at Chart.update (chart.mjs:5687:10)
> at new Chart (chart.mjs:5476:12)
> at renderChart (BaseCharts.ts:126:28)
> at chartCreate (utils.ts:27:3)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-chart-3-chart-js-issue-template-forked-tzhziw?file=/src/App.vue

Import and register seems to be working fine, do you have a reproducable?

Comment: When I ran it on codesandbox it worked fine. Iwonder if there is conflict with my dependencies. I use vite on vue js.

Comment: I dont know, because it is a v3 error, other thing might be that you try to create a chart before importing and registering everything